# All text in website

Tags: plain-text, web, copy-paste

Do we have a program that takes all text in a website? I wanted to know because I want to see a whole website in text and change it a little.

Comment: Do you mean the actual readable text or a text representation of a webpage (HTML)?

Comment: Also do you mean all of the text on a web page or, as asked, all of the text on a site, (which if the site were Stack Exchange would amount to millions of pages).

Comment: I'm asking about all text on a site. Do you think Pandoc will do that?

Comment: @MrPublic I'm thinking about a text representation of a website. Do you know something that will take all text in website?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Do you know a program that takes all of the text on a site?

Comment: Yes - a web crawler such as scrapy can crawl the site asking for all of the content.

Comment: Will it take all the text and show it in one page/file?

Comment: @SteveBarnes I don't know what to do on scrapy. Will you show what I would do before I get all text in website?

Comment: @user6779864: There is a nice walk-though at https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: @SteveBarnes Where do they show where to take all text in website? I don't see it.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Did you see it on scrapy?

Comment: @user6779864 - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html saves all of the content of pages, (as html), in the first spider section and demonstrates using the scrapy shell to get the text from a page.

Comment: Does it take everything or every text in a website or just one page?

Comment: @SteveBarnes                                            ..

Comment: @SteveBarnes Did you see/understand the question I showed you?

Comment: @user6779864 - Yes: Did you __TRY__ following the walk through which shows you _exactly_ how to do what you are asking for.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Oh I see. I didn't do anything or get scrapy because I didn't see anything about taking all text in website. But I will see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html) - "a universal document converter" should be in just about everybody's tool kit.

It is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Just about invaluable

With it you can convert from one format to another, including from online web pages to plain text.

For an example:

```
pandoc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc -f html -t plain -o soq.txt
```

Is asking pandoc to download the hmtl page about itself from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) and convert it to plain text outputting to a file called soq.txt The result looks like:

> PANDOC
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> Jump to: navigation, search
>
> Pandoc Original author(s) John MacFarlane Initial release 10 August
>   2006 (10 years ago) (2006-08-10) Stable release
>   1.19 / 1 December 2016 (3 months ago) (2016-12-01)
>
> Repository github.com/jgm/pandoc Development status Active Written in
>   Haskell Operating system Unix-like, OS X, Windows License GNU GPLv2
>   Website pandoc.org
>   -   []Free software portal
>
> PANDOC is a free and open-source software document converter, widely
>   used as a writing tool (especially by scholars)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc)[3][4] and as a
>   basis for publishing workflows.[5][6][7] It was originally created by
>   John MacFarlane, a philosophy professor at the University of
>   California, Berkeley.[8]
>
> Contents
>
> - 1 Supported file formats
> - 2 Integration with reference managers
> - 3 References
> - 4 External links
>
> Supported file formats[edit]
>
> Pandoc's most thoroughly supported file format is an extended version
>   of Markdown, but it can also read many other forms of lightweight
>   markup language, HTML, ReStructuredText, LaTeX, OPML, Org-mode,
>   DocBook, and Office Open XML (Microsoft Word .docx).
>
> It can be used to create files in many more formats, including Office
>   Open XML, OpenDocument, HTML, Wiki markup, InDesign ICML, web-based
>   slideshows,[9] ebooks,[10] OPML, and various TeX formats (through
>   which it can produce a PDF). It has built-in support for converting
>   LaTeX mathematical equations to MathML and MathJax, among other
>   formats.
>
> Plug-ins for custom formats can also be written in Lua, which has been
>   used to create an exporting tool for the Journal Article Tag
>   Suite.[11]
>
> Integration with reference managers[edit]
>
> An included module, pandoc-citeproc, allows the program to use data
>   from reference management software such as BibTeX, EndNote, Mendeley,
>   or Papers. It has the ability to integrate directly with Zotero.[12]
>   The information is automatically transformed into a citation in
>   various styles (such as APA, Chicago, or MLA) using an implementation
>   of the Citation Style Language. This allows the program to serve as a
>   simpler alternative to LaTeX for producing academic writing.[13]
>
> References[edit]
>
> 1. ^ Mullen, Lincoln (2012-02-23). "Pandoc Converts All Your (Text)
>      Documents". *The Chronicle of Higher Education Blogs: ProfHacker*.
>      Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 2. ^ McDaniel, W. Caleb (2012-09-28). "Why (and How) I Wrote My
>      Academic Book in Plain Text". *W. Caleb McDaniel at Rice
>      University*. Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 3. ^ Healy, Kieran (2014-01-23). "Plain Text, Papers, Pandoc".
>      Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 4. ^ Ovadia, Steven (2014). "Markdown for Librarians and Academics".
>      *Behavioral & Social Sciences Librarian*. 33 (2): 120–124.
>      doi:10.1080/01639269.2014.904696. ISSN 0163-9269.
> 5. ^ Till, Kaitlyn; Shed Simas; Velma Larkai (2014-04-14). "The Flying
>      Narwhal: Small mag workflow". *Publishing @ SFU*. Retrieved
>      2014-06-27.
> 6. ^ Maxwell, John (2013-11-01). "Building Publishing Workflows with
>      Pandoc and Git". *Publishing @ SFU*. Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 7. ^ Maxwell, John (2014-02-26). "On Pandoc". eBound Canada: Digital
>      Production Workshop, Vancouver, BC. Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 8. ^ "John MacFarlane". *Department of Philosophy*. University of
>      California, Berkeley. Retrieved 25 July 2014.
> 9. ^ See as an example MacFarlane, John (2014-05-17). "Pandoc for
>      Haskell Hackers". BayHac 2014, Mountain View, CA. Retrieved
>      2014-06-27.  The source file is written in Markdown.
> 10. ^ Mullen, Lincoln (2012-03-20). "Make Your Own E-Books with Pandoc".
>       *The Chronicle of Higher Education Blogs: ProfHacker*. Retrieved
>       2014-06-27.
> 11. ^ Fenner, Martin (2013-12-12). "From Markdown to JATS XML in one
>       Step". *Gobbledygook*. Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 12. ^ Hetzner, Erik (2014-06-25). "zotxt". Retrieved 2014-06-27.
> 13. ^ Tenen, Dennis; Grant Wythoff (2014-03-19). "Sustainable Authorship
>       in Plain Text using Pandoc and Markdown". *The Programming
>       Historian*. Retrieved 2014-06-27.
>
> External links[edit]
>
> - Official website
> - PanDoc and Wikiversity – PanDocElectron
>
> []
>
> Retrieved from
>   "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pandoc&oldid=756329870"
>
> Categories:
>   -   2006 software
>   -   Free software programmed in Haskell
>   -   Technical communication tools
>   -   Workflow software
>
> Hidden categories:
>   -   Official website different in Wikidata and Wikipedia
>
> Navigation menu
>
> Personal tools
>
> - ### Not logged in
>
> ### Talk
>
> ### Contributions
>
> ### Create account
>
> ```
> Log in
> ```
>
> Namespaces
>
> - ### Article
>
>   Talk
>
> Variants
>
> Views
>
> - ### Read
>
> ### Edit
>
> ```
> View history
> ```
>
> More
>
> Search
>
> Navigation
>
> - ### Main page
>
> ### Contents
>
> ### Featured content
>
> ### Current events
>
> ### Random article
>
> ### Donate to Wikipedia
>
> ```
> Wikipedia store
> ```
>
> Interaction
>
> - ### Help
>
> ### About Wikipedia
>
> ### Community portal
>
> ### Recent changes
>
> ```
> Contact page
> ```
>
> Tools
>
> - ### What links here
>
> ### Related changes
>
> ### Upload file
>
> ### Special pages
>
> ### Permanent link
>
> ### Page information
>
> ### Wikidata item
>
> ```
> Cite this page
> ```
>
> Print/export
>
> - ### Create a book
>
> ### Download as PDF
>
> ```
> Printable version
> ```
>
> Languages
>
> - Deutsch
> - Español
> - Français
> - Русский
> - 中文
>
> Edit links
>
> - ### This page was last modified on 23 December 2016, at 14:17.
>
>   Text is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike
>     License; additional terms may apply. By using this site, you agree
>     to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. Wikipedia® is a registered
>     trademark of the Wikimedia Foundation, Inc., a non-profit
>     organization.
>
> ### Privacy policy
>
> ### About Wikipedia
>
> ### Disclaimers
>
> ### Contact Wikipedia
>
> ### Developers
>
> ### Cookie statement
>
> ```
> Mobile view
> ```
>
> ### [Wikimedia Foundation]
>
> ```
> [Powered by MediaWiki]
> ```